# Storing raw Ionic (Angular) components on bit.dev

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-components, ionic5, bit.dev

The problem:

I would like to use Ionic (for Angular framework) components on bit.dev platform in a raw form.

There are couple of problems I faced trying to do that.

- Ionic has single global ngModule which is exporting all components. No separate module for each component.
- Components in Ionic (Angular ones) are declared in a single file called proxies.ts (which is autogenerated)
- I don't like to change source code of original Ionic components

The aim:

- Having signle source of truth for raw ionic components
- Having visualised raw ionic components collection in bit.dev cloud
- Having possibility to import components via @bit/custom_collection alias, but use
  with original html markup i.e.

`<ion-button></ion-button>`.

- Making another collection / scope (i.e. brand styled components), in which components use raw Ionioc componets (these stored on bit.dev)

Possible solution:

Right now I'm thinking about creation of separate ngModule for each Ionic component in my Workspace , which would
be a bit component as well (exported to a cloud). But on the other hand I need to import Ionic components as
IonicModule.forRoot() in Angular. This would mean that separation of Ionic components by creating ngModules for each, would
be at artificial , and just gives me possibility to visualise it in the could and import. Ofcourse there is also one more advantage - I could force each component to depend on the concrete Ionic framework version ( as a peer dependency).
On the other hand all raw Ionic components stored on bit would rather depend on the same version if Ionic framework.

I assume here also that I need a signle entry file for each bit component , but maybe this assumption is wrong and I should treat
each component not as logical one , but a pure style. So components would be something like that : ionic-button.scss , ionic-title.scss and so on ...
But here I have another problem - as I mention before , I  would like to keep raw Ionic components, so any additional styling here
would likely not happen , what means - files (*.scss) would be empty at all.

Following that examples , this would lead to conclusion that I should try to create component which has no files , but only dependencies
on Ionic framework , Angular etc. and eventually different component example in the cloud. But again - all components would be empty then ,
and have the same dependencies. Is it possible to build it with bit? Are these assumptions correct ?

Maybe someone faced similar problem and have different solutuion.
I would appreciate any thoughts on this.